# CO.Core.Crypto dependency version error

Tags: c#, version, nuget-package

I'm making a C# program using .NET 4.5 implementing the NuGet package `OC.Core.Crypto`

**Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BouncyCastle" version="1.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="OC.Core" version="1.1.14" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="OC.Core.Crypto" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

When I use `OC.Core.Crypto.Hash` an error occurs; `OC.Core.Crypto.Hash Dependency OC.Core version=1.1.12.29464`
I have tried to modify the OC.Core to version 1.1.12.29464, however NuGet can't find that package.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OC.Core;
using OC.Core.Crypto;

namespace qdPayCallBack
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RsaKeyPair rsaKeyPair = new RsaKeyPair(1024);
            priKey.Text = rsaKeyPair.PrivateKey;
            pubKey.Text = rsaKeyPair.PublicKey;
        }

        private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RsaSigner rsa = new RsaSigner(pubKey.Text, priKey.Text);
            OC.Core.Crypto.Hash hash = new OC.Core.Crypto.Hash();//this has an error 
            //错误    2   类型“OC.Core.Object”在未被引用的程序集中定义。必须添加对程序集“OC.Core, Version=1.1.12.29464, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null”的引用。    D:\C#\qdPayCallBack\qdPayCallBack\Form1.cs  36  13  qdPayCallBack

            sign.Text = rsa.Sign(text.Text);
        }

        private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RsaSigner rsa = new RsaSigner(pubKey.Text, priKey.Text);
            //Hash hash = new Hash();
            result.Text = rsa.IsSignatureValid(text.Text, sign.Text).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```